# LDAP invalid login credentials

Tags: spring, ldap, openldap, spring-ldap

I installed sldap on my ubuntu 12.04 system.https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenLDAPServer
I can add /search records to lsdap from terminal.e.g. I can add ldif file.

```
ldapadd -x -D cn=admin,dc=test,dc=com -W -f ldap-add.ldif
```

and it ask me password .I entered pass000 and it added new entry.its working fine .i can add search records from terminal. Now I tried It from my spring application .i added dependency ldap-core to my pom .i set up bean etc. every thing is fine except it gives me error in valid credetials thouh I entered same as I entered while ading ldif file from terminal. My bean configuration is

```
<!-- ldap template -->
    <ldap:context-source id="contextSource" url="ldap://localhost:389"
        base="dc=test,dc=com" username="cn=admin" password="pass000" />

    <ldap:ldap-template id="ldapTemplate"
        context-source-ref="contextSource" />

    <bean id="personDao" class="com.cheasyy.cofinding.dao.PersonDaoImpl">
        <property name="ldapTemplate" ref="ldapTemplate" />
    </bean>
```

It gives error

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]; nested exception is javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:205)
    com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:266)
root cause

org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]; nested exception is javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]
    org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:191)
    org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.createContext(AbstractContextSource.java:356)
    org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.doGetContext(AbstractContextSource.java:140)
```

If with same credentials I can add ldif file from terminal then why not with my spring application?is their anything missing in configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'username' DN needs to be the full DN of the admin user, including the base; in your case:

```
<ldap:context-source id="contextSource" url="ldap://localhost:389"
    base="dc=test,dc=com" username="cn=admin,dc=test,dc=com" password="pass000" />
```

It's not uncommon for the admin user to be located in a different part of the LDAP tree than the base DN from which you want your operations to originate.